# Add a text to a cell after a date

Tags: date, text, formula

I have placed the below formula in a cell which returns the date value -
"02/05/2015". 'Exception Report Register' is the name of the worksheet the formula pulls from and Q:Q the range.

=(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,'Exception Report Register'!Q:Q,1))

I have then formatted the cell so the date will convert to "Saturday, 2 May 2015"

I want to add a full stop to the end to make it "Saturday, 2 May 2015."

I have tried:

=(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,'Exception Report Register'!Q:Q,1))&"." which returns "42126." (as expected)

I have come across the below formula but not sure how to incorporate it

=TEXT(AJ24,"DD/MM/YYYY")&" "&"is Today"

Please help!
Cheers Mallory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to clarify, this question is about formatting dates with the TEXT function in MS Excel.

If your date is in cell A1, try:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dddd, d mmm yyyy")&"."
```

You can substitute 'A1' with your (bizarre) vlookup function.

For more info on date formatting with the TEXT function, see the **Guidelines for date and time formats** section on [MS Office Support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!! I have spent so long on this. I think it was this section of the TEXT formula that I couldn't understand "dddd, d mmm yyyy". Cheers once again!